Why Is My "Hit" Animation Never Appearing and The Force Never Going Away?(GDevelop 5)
After "coding" a few lines of code regarding damage and damage animations, my player continues on the angle forever after it touches one of the "Spikes". It also never runs the damage animation. This is my "code":
Image
This is what happens when I preview it:
https://www.flexclip.com/share/560813508016f38870feb82ec296dac1d5c0d14.html
Additional Info:
Texture Pack: Pixel Adventure
Player:
 Behaviors: Health, Smooth Camera, Smooth Platformer Camera, Platformer Character Animator, Remap For Platformer, Platformer Object.

I tried to add some time in between, but that didn't affect the outcome at all. I also tried to turn it into a temporary force, but then the character didn't move at all. In the end, I tried removing all unnecessary lines, such as changing time scale, but that also had no affect on the outcome.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
